# How to monitor what IP's are connected to my domain

Tags: web

Greetings,

I currently have a website. 
How could I trace the IP that is currently accessing my website?
Could I also trace to what URL of my website they are accessing?

Thanks,
Cyril H.

Answer (score 0):

I think providing a little more information about your website would be good. What type of server is it? Apache, perhaps?

Comment: I forgot to include that. But I'm using Apache Tomcat 6.0 as the server for my website...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Windows server with IIS, open up your IIS Manager, and view the logs for the site in question.

If you are running a *nix box, it would all depend on what web server you have installed, I will assume that its apache, so you could check the apache conf file where the logs are located. Most installations I have seen they are in `/var/log/apache2/` or something similar to `/var/log/httpd` etc;

Then you simply view the files. By default most web servers log requests (access) and errors (failed requests, 404 files/pages).

Should give you all the details you mentioned.  But it depends on what you have running.

Comment: What do you mean by using a Windows server with IIS?